# How do I create a rectangle with a trapezoid bottom in gimp?

Tags: gimp, shapes

Using gimp 2.6.11 on Windows.  How do I create a rectangle with a trapezoid bottom?  I understand to make shapes I should make a selection and then stroke it, but how do I make a selection of this shape?  This is what I'm after:

[image]

I want the length and angles of the corresponding sides to match so I don't want to just draw it by hand.

Comment: for geometric type illustration, most would suggest vector based software. InkScape is a good open source option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I found one way to do this.  Not sure if it's the best way so I'm open to other answers.  Here's what I did.  First I enabled View -> Show Grid and View -> Snap to Grid.  Then I selected the path tool.  Then I clicked once for each of the 6 corners of my shape starting at the top left corner and working my way around clockwise.  Then I held down the control key and click again on the first corner to close the shape.  Then I went to Edit-> Stroke Path.  Voila!

Comment: You can chose this as an answer :)